# How to recursively resize images from one folder to another?

Tags: bash, thumbnails

I would like to create thumbnails of images I have organised into a set of nested subdirectories into a mirror of the file structure so that a command of the type:

```
./imageresize.sh Large Small 10
```

...would convert any .jpg or .JPG files, in the directories nested under "./Large":

```
./Large/Holidays/001.jpg
./Large/Holidays/002.jpg
./Large/Holidays/003.jpg
./Large/Pets/Dog/001.jpg
./Large/Pets/Dog/002.jpg
./Large/Pets/Cat/001.jpg
```

into thumbnails of 10% to a mirror destination with a different top directory ("Small" instead of "Large" in this e.g.):

```
./Small/Holidays/001.jpg
./Small/Holidays/002.jpg
./Small/Holidays/003.jpg
./Small/Pets/Dog/001.jpg
./Small/Pets/Dog/002.jpg
./Small/Pets/Cat/001.jpg
```

This is what I have so far, but I can't seem to get it working. The $newfile variable seems invalid but I don't know why, and when testing, it outputs the result of the 'convert' command to the screen. Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

#manage whitespace and escape characters
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

#create file list
filelist=$(find ./$1/ -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.JPG")

for file in $filelist
do

#create destination path for 'convert' command
newfile= ${file/$1/$2}

convert "$file" -define jpeg:extent=10kb -scale $3% "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: Haven't looked at anything else, but at least there is a space after `newfile=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's just a copy/paste error or if it's actually in your script, but this line:

```
newfile= ${file/$1/$2}
```

would be an invalid assignment in Bash as spaces around `=` isn't allowed when assigning.

Try this instead:

```
newfile=${file/$1/$2}
```

As a side-note. `find` has a case-insensitive search too, `-iname`, so you could do:

```
filelist=$(find ./$1/ -iname "*.jpg")
```

It also has `-exec` for executing commands on the result set. It's explained very well here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec So you may be able to do it in one single `find`. (Note: That's not necessarily better, in most cases it's just a matter of preference, I just mention it as a possibility.)

Comment: Thankyou for the reply! ...and the -iname option is perfect. I've corrected the formatting as you suggested and it fixed one issue that I didn't actually realise was an issue, and I've just found the other problem which is that I need the directories to be created before converting! So I've added the line: rsync -a --include '*/' --exclude '*' ./$1/ ./$2/ - not very elegant, but it works -  I'll post the working script as a separate answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So - revised working script with corrections suggested by madsen and 4ae1e1 (thanks both), and with rsync commands to create directory structure first, (then clean extraneous files from the destination) :).  I've added an extra parameter and parameter checker so that now you can specify source, destination, approx destination file size in kb and percentage of original.  Hope it helps someone else. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

#manage whitespace and escape characters
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

#check parameters
if [ $# -lt 4 ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]
then # if no parameters or '--help' as $1 - show help
    echo "______________________________________________________________"
    echo ""
    echo "Useage: thumbnailmirror [Source] [Destination] [Filesize] [Percentage]"
    echo "Source - e.g. 'Fullsize' (directory must exist)" 
    echo "Destination - e.g. 'Thumnail' (directory must exist)"
    echo "Filesize - approx filesize in kb  e.g. '10'"
    echo "Percentage - % of reduction (1-100)"
    echo "e.g. thumbnailmirror Fullsize Thumnail 18 7"
    echo "______________________________________________________________"


else # parameters exist
    #syncronise directory structure (directories only)
    rsync -a --include '*/' --exclude  '*'  ./$1/ ./$2/
    # delete any extraneous files and directories at destination
    rsync -a --delete --existing --ignore-existing ./$1/ ./$2/
    #create file list ( -iname means not case sensitive)
    filelist=$(find ./$1/ -iname "*.jpg")

    for file in $filelist
      do
      #define destination filename for 'convert' command
      newfile=${file/$1/$2}

      if [ ! -f "$newfile" ] #if file doesn't exists create it
      then
          convert "$file" -define jpeg:extent=$3kb -quality 100 -scale $4% "$newfile"
          echo "$file resized"
      else #skip it
          echo "Skipping $file - exists already"
      fi
      done
fi
```

Comment: A script that starts with `OIFS="$IFS"` and `IFS=$'\n'` is very likely a broken script!

Comment: It seems to work for me as it is, I copied and pasted that bit in an attempt to handle whitespace/escape characters from another script, but if you could point me in the right direction to correct the mistake I'd be grateful! :)

Comment: Well, things will badly break when you have glob characters (e.g., `*`, `?`, `[` or `]`) or newlines in your filenames. A good pointer, to start with, is this one: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out. :)